# How is NodeJS handling module caching when same module is required with multiple versions

Tags: node.js

For a project with a structure like:

```
  index.js => require('debug')
           => require('express')
  node_modules
    debug => version 3.x.x
    express => require('debug')
      node_modules
        debug => version 2.x.x
```

1. NodeJS loads the debug module required in index.js, with a 3.x.x version
2. When the debug module is loaded for the express module, does NodeJS uses the already cached debug module (v3.x.x) or it loads the one required by the express module (2.x.x) ?

Comment: Yes, they are [cached](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching): `Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.`

Comment: I read that in the nodejs documentation and it's not clear for me what do they mean by "same file". Is it same file name , same file absolute path, same file content ?

Comment: Your example above is requiring a [core module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) as it does not start with a path i.e. `/` or './` etc or contain and extension. Node will look in the project's `node_modules` folder, then the [global](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) node_modules folder and check versions stipulated in `package.json`. Otherwise, node looks at the path you have specified - which is case sensitive and will cache the file and serve that for future requests that point to the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The module cache is not just by the root filename, it's by their fully resolved path.

So, if module "A" is loading v3.xx of index.js and module "B" is loading v2.xx of index.js from a different disk location, then both will get loaded since the module cache recognizes them as different files and will cache them separately.

So, since v3.xx and v2.xx of `index.js` can't ever possibly exist at the same full path, the whole system works just fine as each module can `require()` in the precise version of each dependent module that it comes with.

This assumes that modules are well-behaved and aren't doing things that might ruin this ability such as establishing globals that might conflict or competing for locking of shared resources, etc...  If they are well behaved modules, then a project can have one module using v3.xx and another module using v2.xx.  This is made possible by the separate scopes of each module and the ability for each dependent module to import them each separately.

> I read that in the nodejs documentation and it's not clear for me what do they mean by "same file". Is it same file name , same file absolute path, same file content ?

It's is the same full path so something like:

```
/whatever/user/someUser/myProject/node_modules/index.js
```

would be a full path to index.js.

If you don't specify a full path to `require()` as in `require('index.js');` or you specific a relative path, then it will be the full path on which `require()` finds the index.js according to the search rules specified for `require()` (as specified in the doc).